# Is shape morphism invariant to the cardinality of the set of components/quasicomponents?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, connectedness, morphism

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces. We denote with $CX$ and $CY$ the sets of connected components and $QX$ and $QY$ the sets of quasicomponents for the corresponding spaces.
It is well known that if $X$ and $Y$ are homotopic, then $|CX|=|CY|$ and $|QX|=|QY|$.

Is there a similar claim (or a known counterexample) when spaces $X$ and $Y$ are shape morphic?

Comment: shape morphic = having the same shape in the sense of Borsuk-Mardesic-Segal?

Comment: @paul frost yes.